# Insert data into Aurora DB from Kinesis Stream using Amazon Web Services Lambda Function

Tags: python, beginner, mysql, error-handling

I have a python AWS lambda function that takes JSON records, checks them to see if they have required keys, and then inserts into MySQL db. The function gets invoked whenever a new record comes into the stream `def handler`.

I'm looking for feedback on the `class` I've created, as well as implementing better exception handling - at the moment, Lambda is reporting some errors, but when I look at logs I don't see any errors, which leads me to believe that maybe I'm not catching them.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import base64
import json
import pymysql

RDS_HOST = 'host'

DB_USER = 'dummy_user'
DB_PASSWORD = 'password1234'
DB_NAME = 'crazy_name'
DB_TABLE = 'wow_table'

class MYSQL(object):
    '''
    This a wrapper Class for PyMySQL
    '''
    CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30

    def __init__(self, host, user, password, database, table):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.database = database
        self.table = table
        self.connection = self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        '''
        Connects to MySQL instance
        '''
        try:
            connection = pymysql.connect(
                host=self.host, 
                user=self.user, 
                password=self.password, 
                db=self.database, 
                connect_timeout=self.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
                )

            return connection

        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            print("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to AuroraDB instance")

    def execute(self, account_id, external_ref_id, timestamp):
        '''
        Executes command given a MySQL connection
        '''

        with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = ('INSERT INTO ' + 
                   self.database + 
                   '.' + 
                   self.table +
                   '(`account_id`, `external_reference_id`, `registration`, `c_name`, `c_id`, `create_date`)' +
                   ' VALUES (%s, %s, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(%s,"%%Y-%%M-%%d %%H:%%i:%%s"),"%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%i:%%s"), %s, %s, current_timestamp())' + 
                   ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE create_date = VALUES(create_date)')
            cursor.execute(sql, (
                account_id, 
                external_ref_id, 
                timestamp, 
                'bingo', 
                300)
                          )

            self.connection.commit()

    def close_connection(self):
        '''
        Closes connection to MySQL
        '''
        self.connection.close()

def get_data_from_kinesis_object(obj):
    '''
    Retrieves data from kinesis event
    '''
    return obj['kinesis']['data']

def decode_data(data):
    '''
    Decodes record via base64
    '''
    return base64.b64decode(data)

def split_records_into_record(records):
    '''
    Splits a record of records into an array of records
    '''
    return records.split('\n')

def parse_record(record):
    '''
    parses record into JSON
    '''

    if record:

        return json.loads(record)

def is_record_valid(record):
    '''
    Check for keys in event
    returns True if they all exist
    and False if they dont all exist

    '''
    return all(key in record for key in (
        'eventName', 
        'sourceType',
        'AccountId',
        'Timestamp',
        'ExternalReferenceId'
        ))

def handler(event, context):
    """
    This function inserts data into Aurora RDS instance
    """

    mysql = MYSQL(RDS_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_TABLE)

    for obj in event['Records']:
        records = decode_data(get_data_from_kinesis_object(obj))
        split_records = split_records_into_record(records)

        for record in split_records:
            parsed_record = parse_record(record)

            if is_record_valid(parsed_record):
                mysql.execute(
                    parsed_record['AccountId'],
                    parsed_record['ExternalReferenceId'],
                    str(parsed_record['Timestamp'])
                    )

    mysql.close_connection()
```

Answer (score 3):

This one is a bit tricky because it seems easy enough to use your data like this but it's not ok to ask your database to create all these short lived connections.  [This article](https://blog.spotinst.com/2017/11/19/best-practices-serverless-connection-pooling-database/) is a nice summary of the issue and a nice, short, easy to understand implementation.

One solution I'm going to try to implement is connection pooling.  There's lots of info out there from the interwebz, so I won't bother pasting piles of links but try to search for something like `connection pools in AWS Lambda`.

Another approach would be to use your lambda to put this data into a Queue or a stream or something and allow another service to consume those messages and do the database CRUD, using its long lived connection.

It's more work but there are some nice tools out there to help speed it up, so much so that the difference between implementing connection pooling and a message streaming system is negligible.  I like to use something called [Stacker](https://stacker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create my systems. That can help if connection pooling won't work for you.

I'd be interested in hearing about your solution, though.  Sorry I'm late to the game but since I'm researching this problem right now, I thought I'd post this for others who might land here but haven't had as much luck finding "proper" solutions.

Cheers